# How can i look at tensorflow hub model arheticture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I want to copy the code for mobile net v2 96x96 layers, define my own model and train from zero, how can I do it?

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_96/feature_vector/2
https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_96/feature_vector/2

Answer (score 1):

actually i have same problem like you and the way i think you solve this problem is to cache the module from hub and take a look at it in tensorboard
this links may help you
https://medium.com/@daj/how-to-inspect-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-5fd2ee79ced0

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/basics

if i could do it i update the response with code